# Request Attribute not found after Spring Security added to Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application that is running. As soon as I added Spring Security, the app generated an error.

I have a form that is backed by a bean. When I enable Spring Security, the bean for the form cannot be found. Before I added Spring Security, the bean and form worked.

The error that I receive after making a GET request to the form is

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'orderActive' available as request attribute
```

The form is using the ThymeLeaf package.

**Spring Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("buzz")
        .password("{noop}infinity")
        .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

}
```

**Controller Method**

```
    @GetMapping("/orders/current")
    public String orderForm() {
        return "orderForm";
    }
```

**Test Class Annotations**

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class DesignTacoControllerTest {
```

**Test Method**

```
    @WithMockUser("buzz")
    @Test
    public void testProcessDesignGet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/orders/current")
                .requestAttr("orderActive", new Order()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

**orderForm**

```
    <form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${orderActive}">
```

I have tried adding a RequestAttribute to the controller method.

```
    @GetMapping("/orders/current")
    public String orderForm(@RequestAttribute("orderActive") Order orderActive) {
        return "orderForm";
    }
```

When I debug, the order has the same ID as the one that was added in the test method. The next step is to render the view. When I continue, the error appears.

Somewhere between the controller method and the view, the request parameter disappears. It has something to do with security, since the code runs without security enabled. The order form is found, so the page is not forbidden. Does security disable the request attributes?

Comment: You have to check if the orderactive property is valid. Bindingresult detected an error on the object orderactive.

Answer (score 1):

You say it worked before Security, but, do you have a class (DTO) OrderForm with the fields you need in your form? I don't see one. If you don't create one and then add it to the model (that's the Binding part):

```
@GetMapping("/orders/current")
    public String orderForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("orderForm", new OrderForm())
        return "orderForm";
    }
```

Comment: I have simplified the example. I am actually trying to access a session attribute. I do not want to map the session attribute to a form in the page.